# Only wallpaper shows after install 13.04

Tags: system-installation

After I succesfully installed Ubuntu 13.04. After I log in I get a blank screen only showing me the wallpaper and a mouse which I can move (so it didn't freeze. I installed Ubuntu 13.04 from my usb with the pendrive installer as explained on the official website. I installed Ubuntu over windows.

Comment: This problem sounds like a bug described here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1083132